# throw exception in java, throws and then continue error

Tags: java, exception

this is the new exception class I wrote:

```
package Q1;

public class EqualException extends Exception {

    public EqualException()
    {
    }

    public EqualException(String message){
        super(message);
    }

}
```

and this is the try and catch:

```
public SortedPair(T first, T second){
    try{
        if(((Comparable <T>)first).compareTo(second)>0){
        this.bigNum = first;
                                                this.smallNum = second;
    }
    else if(((Comparable <T>)first).compareTo(second)<0){
        this.smallNum = first;
        this.bigNum = second;
    }
    else throw new EqualException("IllegalPair Exception");
    }
    catch(EqualException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is part of the main who send to the SortedPair constructor:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int num1=0,num2=0;
        ArrayList<SortedPair> sotredPairsArray = new ArrayList<SortedPair>(); //List of sorted pairs
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        SortedPair sotredPair;

        System.out.println("Enter pairs of numbers");
        System.out.println("to finish enter 0 ");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

        do{
            System.out.println("Enter First number in the pair: ");
            num1 = scan.nextInt();
            if(num1!=0){
                System.out.println("Enter Second number in the pair: ");
                num2 = scan.nextInt();
                sotredPair = new SortedPair(num1, num2);
                sotredPairsArray.add(sotredPair);
            }
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        }while(num1!=0 && num2!=0);
```

my question is, why after exception i don't immediately stop running and I see one more message in the console of:
"---------------------------------------
Enter First number in the pair: 
"

Comment: ehm ... I don't see you print that anywhere in the code you posted, so a bit hard to say. but just because that part of the flow is interrupted, doesn't mean the entire flow is.

Comment: added part of the main who prints it....

Comment: You don't immediately stop running because your code does not have a condition to exit when you catch the exception.

Comment: how do I add condition to exit when I catch the exception?

Comment: When you catch the Exception you only print the trace but you don't throw the exception so is normal your program follows running.

Comment: Throwing an exception seems like *a rather extreme* way to handle equality, which in any reasonable application would be a somewhat common case (and one easily tested against).

Answer (score 0):

change you constructor of SortedPair to:

```
public SortedPair(T first, T second) throws EqualException {
        if (((Comparable<T>) first).compareTo(second) > 0) {
            this.bigNum = first;
            this.smallNum = second;
        } else if (((Comparable<T>) first).compareTo(second) < 0) {
            this.smallNum = first;
            this.bigNum = second;
        } else
            throw new EqualException("IllegalPair Exception");
}
```

and catch the exception in main

Comment: I think, there should be `Comparable <? extends T>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I (and I suppose the compiler) understand from your code :

- you have a try block in which an exception is thrown
- the exception is caught in catch block (still in SortedPair constructor)
- you print the exception stack trace (I suppose you can see it on your console)
- and you continue in sequence after the catch block (it is its use after all)

So it is perfectly normal that your program displays one more message.

If you want to stop after the error, you can either not catch the Exception in SortedPair constructor (neither try nor catch block) or throw it again in catch block :

```
catch(EqualException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
}
```

But the way, catching an exception just for logging purpose and throwing it again in catch block is considered bad practice : *if you can't fix it don't catch it*.